# Garantir uma Transação

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho uma tabela de Etiquetas com o RG sequencial incrementado na mão, pois ela zera a cada dia.

Possuo uma tela de cadastro de Etiquetas onde eu passo a quantidade de etiquetas a serem geradas:

```
Vrg := Select MAX onde eu pego o maior RG.
qtETQ := quantidade de etiquetas, por exemplo 500 etiquetas digitada pelo usuario 
i := 0
while i <= qtEtq do  //loop de 500 vezes
begin
  Vrg := Vrg+1 
  etiqueta.rg := Vrg
  etiqueta.post
end
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Se eu tiver duas telas abertas, pode acontecer de terem etiquetas duplicadas.
Existe uma forma de contornar isso?

Comment: uma alternativa é antes de você inserir no banco verificar se já existe uma etiqueta cadastrada com aquele rg, se existir gerar um código novo senão continua adicionando.

Comment: Não sei se você dá o *commit* apenas no final do laço ou o **etiqueta.post** já *commita* a informação no banco. Porém caso o *commit* seja dado apenas no final (recomendado), sugiro você trabalhar com uma *sequence* (tal qual o Oracle faz). Se não for Oracle, você pode simular uma *sequence*, garantindo a exclusividade da etiqueta.

Comment: @Andrey como eu simulo essa sequence no delphi? Estou usado o Firebird

Comment: Você pode montar um *Generator* no Firebird e cada dia, quando for o primeiro acesso zerar o *Generator* (Nesse caso o próprio SGDB garantirá o RG único). Se tentar controlar a nível de aplicação, ou deixar a tabela em Lock ou então commitar a cada novo registro.

Comment: A aplicação chega a mostrar algum erro?

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução que pode impactar na performance, mas que vai resolver o problema é a cada iteração do loop você dar o "select max + 1" no campo do rg.

Não sei exatamente qual o porte da sua aplicação e da sua infra-estrutura, dependendo pode ser uma péssima ideia ou então algo tolerável.

Uma opção que você poderia tentar seria deixar esse campo como auto incremento, mas aí tem a questão de zera sua contagem todo dia.

Comment: Valeu pela dica, mas resolvi criando uma tabela separada no bando de dados, que controla se pode ou não gerar as etiquetas.

Comment: Seria uma boa você colocar uma resposta pra sua própria pergunta mostrando como você fez para solucionar, isso pode ser útil para mais pessoas.